# Passing HTML values to url with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am fairly new to PHP and Javascript programming. Currently I am working on a checkout component for an ecommerce website. I have an amount value for a product that is inside a span element and it's changing value according to the quantity the user selects. I need to grab these two values (quantity and value) and pass them to another PHP page. What's the best approach for doing this?

[image]

```
</div> <!-- slider-nav.// -->
    </article> <!-- gallery-wrap .end// -->
        </aside>
        <aside class="col-sm-7">
    <article class="p-5">
    <h3 class="title mb-3" id="product-title">Colocar o nome do produto </h3>

<div class="mb-3"> 
    <var class="price h3 text-warning"> 
        <span class="currency">EU €</span><span class="num" id="big_valor">29.99</span>
    </var> 

</div> <!-- price-detail-wrap .// -->
<dl>
  <dt>Descrição</dt>
  <dd><p>Here goes description consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p></dd>
</dl>
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Modelo</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">12345611</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Cor</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Azul e Branco </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Entrega</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Portugal e Espanha</dd>
</dl>

<hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <dl class="dlist-inline">
              <dt>Quantidade: </dt>
              <dd> 
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:70px;" onchange="calcular();" id="selector">
                    <option> 1 </option>
                    <option> 2 </option>
                    <option> 3 </option>
                </select>
              </dd>
            </dl>  <!-- item-property .// -->
        </div> <!-- col.// -->

    </div> <!-- row.// -->
    <hr>
    <a href="customer_order_form.php" class="btn  btn-primary" click="sendInfo();"> Comprar </a>

</article> <!-- card-body.// -->
        </aside> <!-- col.// -->
    </div> <!-- row.// -->
</div> <!-- card.// -->
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item-gallery a").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'   :   800, 
        'speedOut'  :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'cyclic'    :   true,


    }).click(function(e){
        var image_name = $(this).attr('href');  $(".img-big-wrap div a img").attr('src',image_name);

    })

}); //END OF DOCUMENT READY

function calcular(){

let select_value = document.getElementById("selector").value;
let amount = select_value*29.99;
$('#big_valor').html(amount);
}
```

Comment: Instead of a spammy image, please show the code you have.

Comment: The *fairly new to PHP* and the *working on a checkout component* aren't two terms I would like to see together in any scenario.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer with the code.

Comment: So for starters, do you  know how to use Javascript to post data to PHP?  If not, do some research on ajax, and then make an attempt.  When you have something that at least looks like it _should_ work, update your question with what you tried, the actual result, the expected result, and what debugging you have already done.

Comment: Yes. I have used Javascript to post data to PHP using AJAX. But my question is how I can grab that ammount value and pass it to another php page without resorting to forms

Comment: If you know how to use ajax, then your question should have nothing to do with "and pass it to another php page".  If you only want to know how to grab the text of an element with jquery, see [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Are you trying to determine the price in an actual shop? If so, please be aware that not only is it very easy for anyone to change the price in the element, it is also easy to change any data sent from the user to the server. Price should be retrieved by the server from the database.

Comment: Hello Trobol. This is a one product page. The user selects the quantity and the price gets updated accordingly. In the following page he fills the order form and finally checks out. Its a three step process. So my question is whats the best approach to obtain the ammount value and the quantity in the final step/page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `quantity` and `value` to PHP and save it in a session. Then you first look for these 2 values in the session and if you won't find them then `quantity` and `value` will be your default values.

**Edit:** I recommend you to send only `quantity` to PHP and calculate the price based on the product price you have in your database. If you send the price from your frontend and then you use it in your order, user may change the product price and you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you very much